# event.target selects all its parents

Tags: jquery, events, repeat

if i click any of the LI, i get all of it's parents or closest selected one by one in reverse order.

i..e.

```
<ul id="cssmenu_mfarooqi">
        <li>menu1</li>
        <li>menu2
            <ul>
                <li>menu11-0</li>
                <li>menu12-1
                    <ul>
                        <li>menu12-11-0</li>
                        <li>menu12-12-0</li>
                        <li>menu12-13-1
                            <ul>
                                <li>menu12-13-11</li>
                                <li>menu12-13-12</li>
                                <li>menu12-13-13</li>
                                <li>menu12-13-14</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>menu12-14-0</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>menu13-0</li>
                <li>menu14-0</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>menu3</li>
```

now.. using jquery with following lines of code..

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('li').click(function (e) {
        console.log(e.target);
     });
  });
```

.... now if i click on **menu1**  and i get following result in console.

```
<li>menu1</li>
```

and that is perfect..

now if i click on **menu11-0** then i get following lines in console

```
<li>menu11-0<li>
<li>menu11-0<li>
```

and i click on **menu12-13-11** get following result in console

```
<li>​menu12-13-14​</li>​
<li>​menu12-13-14​</li>​
<li>​menu12-13-14​</li>​
```

... items with sub levels are shown on console with complete children ULs..

... I'm using actually click to further process with current object. but i'm not getting proper result.

Here is the preview http://jsfiddle.net/mfarooqi/y5mftnee/1/

Comment: OK. What is your question?

Comment: :D sorry. I must highlight the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to log in the console only once.

Then, just stop the propagation of the event:

```js
$('li').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

The problem is that events propagate:

[image: graphical representation of an event dispatched in a DOM tree using the DOM event flow]

In your case, the event listener is triggered for the target element and, during the bubble phase of the event, for all of its `li` ancestors.

But if you stop the propagation of the event, it will not bubble anymore, so the event listener won't be triggered for the ancestors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the click event propagating to ancetor elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log(e.target);
    });
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gfz6ra5/)

Comment: Thanks .. your answer was correct too .. even i answered my own question i couldnt' select mine.. but oriol was on top.

Comment: @MFarooqi, no wonder you selected Oriol's answer. Anyone who uses that many crayons deserves the points!

Answer (score 1):

It is correct behavior, since the `LI` tags are nested. You'll need `event.stopPropagation()` it prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event:

```
$('li').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // your code...
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5mftnee/3/) is here.

Comment: Thanks .. your answer was correct too .. even i answered my own question i couldnt' select mine.. but oriol was on top.

Answer (score 0):

oops.. it was just simple. I have been searching on the net. and found solution.

Here is the details [Jquery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

this effect is called bubbling. same event is called that many times if siblings matches.

the solution is .

right after click function i had to stop bubbling by following line of code.

I don't know if this is the only solution, but suggestions and reason still required...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('li').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        console.log(e.target);
     });
  });
```

This worked for me.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 .. you are right. I just copied from the jquery docs and pasted here.. this is not the issue. but it is working now

Comment: I saw your correction as soon as I posted my comment - and deleted it immediately.